# Clearing all CellTags in a notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, cells

Below is some code that will delete all `CellTags` in a notebook where the `CellTag` is given by the string `"temp"`.

```
NotebookLocate[{InputNotebook[], "temp"}];
SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[], CellTags -> {}];
```

However, I want delete every `CellTag` in the notebook so there are none left at all.  I tried replacing `"temp"` with `*` but that doesn't work.  Any ideas here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
Scan[SetOptions[#, CellTags -> {}] &, Cells[InputNotebook[]]]
```

Comment: This does evaluate faster.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
NotebookPut[NotebookGet@#/.(CellTags->_)->Sequence[],#]&@InputNotebook[];
```

This removes all the celltags in the current notebook.

Comment: Updated to overwrite the current notebook in one step

Comment: I was about to say... I needed a solution for the current notebook.  But looks like you got it solved.   Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! I must say it's really pleasing to see how Mathematica lets you seamlessly integrate pattern matching, pure functions, and the fact that everything is an expression.

Comment: @Kuba Hmm. It didn't show up when I opened the cell tags from the menu. I'll check the notebook expression.

Comment: @Kuba It did disappear from the notebook expression without any error messages in version 11.0 on Windows. I'm actually surprised that it works :D

Comment: hmmm... yes... I'm getting the warning message "An improperly formatted option was encountered. The left-hand side of the option was not a symbol or string."

Comment: Updated to fix the error message